# Method [save] does not exist. laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

**DocumentController:**

```php
$document = new Document();
$input = Input::all();

$document->first_name = Auth::user()->first_name;
$document->last_name = Auth::user()->last_name;
$document->document = $input['title'];
$document->document = $input['body'];
$document->save();

$parent = new Parent();
$parent->title = $input['title'];
$parent->save();
```

**Parent Model**

```php
class Parent extends \Eloquent {

}
```

The first `save()` instance is working fine, but the other one is throwing an error Method [save] does not exist.

**Document Model**

```php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Document extends Eloquent implements UserInterface,     RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

}
```

**Updated Parent Model**

```php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Parent extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

}
```

Comment: uh, well, can you post your `Document` class? is it a model too? *Method [save] does not exist* -- but you have two object that calls `->save()`.. not to mention no stacktrace.. it'll be a bit harder to pin point the problem. anyway, what does `dd($parent)` gave you?

Comment: Yes, first save() method actually saves the data, only the save() method connected to $parent object is throwing an error.

Comment: hmm, i wonder what was wrong, but i'm a bit suspicious on that `extends \Eloquent`. it's been a while since i touch laravel 4.2, but [in this example](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage) they did not use `extends \Eloquent` (means on the root namespace) but plaintly `extends Eloquent` (namespace covered by `using Illuminate\Database\Eloquent`). Not to mention Eloquent Model [is located in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php). but can't be sure, unless taking a peek on whole Parent class tops.

Comment: Just inserted dd($parent) before save() and got this 'code'object(BaseController)#203 (4) { ["beforeFilters":protected]=> array(0) { } ["afterFilters":protected]=> array(0) { } ["layout":protected]=> NULL ["title"]=> string(9) "qweqweqwe" }

Comment: hmm, `object(BaseController)#203` i think it did not extend the Eloquent `Model` class properly, try to fix it first -- take a look on your `Document` Model, you gotta get a clue.

Comment: Actually I already copied, pasted and edited the code from the User.php file, but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: do you mind to post your latest model (`Parent` and `Document`)..? i'm getting curious..

Comment: I have update my question and added the codes. Document model works fine though.

Comment: i've read your code.. alas, i got no idea how it still not working..